# Keep Changes in Layout - Android

Tags: android, button, layout

I got a Dynamic layout, that creates TextView when I push a Button, the TextView shows information... I want that all TextView created in the layout be save when the aplicacation closes and when the system (phone or tablet) be off.

How can I do that?

Comment: I feel that you will have to use one of the Android ways to persist information. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to make a class with arraylist of strings that will contain the text. The order of the TextViews will be the index of the text in the ArrayList. You need that this class will implenent Serializable interface. Then on onStop() you should save it using dataOutputStream . The last thing to do is to open the file and create the TextViews programaticaly in your onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a shared preference object like that : 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

Comment: But if I want to add new Views(Buttons, TextView) how can I do that the aplication save that and when I closes de app and I open again the layout has the modification?